# build plot by elements matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to build up a plot element-by-element? For instance, in R you can do something like

```
plot.new()                      ## start a new plot
plot.window(c(0,10),c(0,10))    ## set data limits
lines(1:10)                     ## draw a line
points(1:10)                    ## draw points
axis(1)                         ## draw x axis
axis(2)                         ## draw y axis
box()                           ## draw box around figure
```

So far all the functions I know in pyplot begins with plotting a graphic with all elements and either hiding, removing, or modifying them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can control all the aspects of a plot, but it is not straightforward. You have to start from a matplotlib.pyplot.axes object, and add stuff. For example, lines are added with: matplotlib.pyplot.axhline() and matplotlib.pyplot.axvline(). I find easier to start from something. Another good trick is to check the gallery of examples. Than usually gives you something pretty close to what you want.